# How to judge a variable's type as string or integer

Tags: bash

This is my code:

```
if [ $value == "^[[:digit:]]*$" ]
then
    echo "number"
else
    echo "other"
fi
```

It seems that the program never echoes "number" even if I set `value=1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`test` doesn't do regexs.

```
[[ $value =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  Also important is that the OP needs to not have quotes around the regex.  Plus the question was missing a `then` ...

Comment: could I ask that what `~` refers to?

Comment: Short answer: =~ is a distinct operator, just like == and !=