# bash -- how to judge if a variable is a string or number

Tags: bash

In bash shell, how do we judge if a variable is a string or number? Here, number could be an integer or a float. This link ["How to judge a variable's type as string or integer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516611/how-to-judge-a-variables-type-as-string-or-integer) seems to only work integer.

Comment: And you didn't try adapting that for floats?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test if a variable is a number in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could expand the proposed regular expression, dependent on the desired number format(s):

`[[ $value =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]` would recognize 2 or 2.4 as a number but 2. or .4 as a string.

`[[ $value =~ ^(\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)$ ]]` would recognize all 2, 2.4, 2. and .4 as numbers

Answer (score 4):

Based on referred question, following does the job for me:

```
[[ $value =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]
```

Comment: You'll need to escape the `.`, otherwise it will match `2c2` and the like.

Comment: correct, I had it in my post, just seems like it was rendered without it, thanks for remark, updated my solution